# Unable to use dynamically imported modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, import, module

I'm dynamically importing any *.py* modules that are not the `__init__.py` or my `skeleton.py` files from a subdirectory. I first build a list that looks like (*.py is omitted*):

```
mods_in_dir = ['my_mods.frst_mod','my_mods.scnd_mod']
```

*my_mods* beign the subdirectory, *frst_mod.py* and *sncd_mod.py* being the available modules. All modules I import contain the `class Operation` and it offers always the same three functions. Then I import them using importlib.

```
import importlib

imports = {}

for i in mods_in_dir:
   imports[i] = importlib.import_module(i)
```

Which results in apparently successful imports, as I checked it by `print(sys.modules.keys())`, where they show up as `[...], 'my_mods.frst_mod', 'my_mods.scnd_mod', [...]`.

For testing reasons I defined a function in every of the modules:

```
def return_some_string():
    return "some string"
```

But I'm unable to call this function. I've tried everything that came to my mind.. e.g. `print(my_mods.frst_mod.Operation.return_some_string())` or `print(frst_mod.Operation.return_some_string())`

Both resulting in `NameError: name 'my_mods' is not defined` or `NameError: name 'frst_mod' is not defined`

edit:
**Solved.**

@m170897017 helped me solve the problem in my initial attempt.
I missed that I had the modules in the `imports` dict and didn't use that.

`print(imports['my_mods.frst_mod'].ModsClassName.return_some_string())` now successfully prints `some_string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change dynamic import to this way and try again:

```
...
mods_in_dir = ['my_mods.frst_mod','my_mods.scnd_mod']
modules = list(map(__import__, mods_in_dir))
# if you want to invoke func1 in my_mods.frst_mod and get result from it
result1 = modules[0].func1()
# if you want to invoke func2 in my_mods.scnd_mod and get result from it
result2 = modules[1].func2()
...
```

Comment: I just tried just like you suggested, but I'm still unable to use the function, plus are the modules not even mentioned in `sys.modules.keys()`.. edit: I do get `<map object at 0x02AA0F30>` after the `map` command..

Comment: @DaedalusMythos What's the error message? The same?

Comment: Yes, I do get the same error.. `name '..' is not defined`

Comment: @DaedalusMythos It's the way you call function is not right. Check my update.

Comment: thanks but this is very odd to handle. It seems to be working but I receive no output from the functions, nor can I choose which module I'm using this way.

Comment: just tried it and I get: `TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63463/discussion-between-m170897017-and-daedalus-mythos).